# Proper use Generator typing

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

I'm attempting to add typing to a method that returns a generator. Whenever I run this program with the return type specified, a TypeError is raised.

Adding quotes or removing the typing fixes the error, but this seems like hack. Surely there is a correct way of doing this.

```py
def inbox_files(self) -> "Generator[RecordsFile]":
    ...

# OR

def inbox_files(self):
    ...
```

```py
from typing import Generator, List
from .records_file import RecordsFile

Class Marshaller:

    ...

    def inbox_files(self) -> Generator[RecordsFile]:
        return self._search_directory(self._inbox)

    def _search_directory(self, directory: str) -> RecordsFile:
        for item_name in listdir(directory):
            item_path = path.join(item_name, directory)
            if path.isdir(item_path):
                yield from self._search_directory(item_path)
            elif path.isfile(item_path):
                yield RecordsFile(item_path)
            else:
                print(f"[WARN] Unknown item found: {item_path}")
```

The following stack trace is produced:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./bin/data_marshal", line 8, in <module>
    from src.app import App
  File "./src/app.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .marshaller import Marshaller
  File "./src/marshaller.py", line 9, in <module>
    class Marshaller:
  File "./src/marshaller.py", line 29, in Marshaller
    def inbox_files(self) -> Generator[RecordsFile]:
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/typing.py", line 254, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/typing.py", line 630, in __getitem__
    _check_generic(self, params)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/typing.py", line 208, in _check_generic
    raise TypeError(f"Too {'many' if alen > elen else 'few'} parameters for {cls};"
TypeError: Too few parameters for typing.Generator; actual 1, expected 3
```

¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 34):

You have to explicitly specify the send type and the return type, even if both are `None`.

```
def inbox_files(self) -> Generator[RecordsFile,None,None]:
    return self._search_directory(self._inbox)
```

Note that the yield type is what you might think of as the return type. The send type is the type of value you can pass to the generator's `send` method. The return type is the type of value that could be embedded in the `StopIteration` exception raised by `next` after all possible value have been yielded. Consider:

```
def foo():
    yield 3
    return "hi"

f = foo()
```

The first call to `next(f)` will return 3; the second will raise `StopIteration("hi")`.
)

---

A generator that you cannot send into or return from is simply an iterable or an iterator (either, apparently can be used).

```
def inbox_files(self) -> Iterable[RecordsFile]:  # Or Iterator[RecordsFile]
    return self._search_directory(self._inbox)
```

`_search_directory` itself *also* returns a generator/iterable, not an instance of `RecordsFile`:

```
def _search_directory(self, directory: str) -> Iterable[RecordsFile]:
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind and clear explanation. There is more to Python's generators than I knew. I'll have to review the documentation so I can take full advantage of them.

Comment: Could you please provide a pointer to the documentation of `Generator[T1, T2, T3]`?

Comment: Answering myself for posterity, it seems to be documented here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Generator

Answer (score -1):

This answer was useful, but I was confused since I was sure I had used Generator[] with just one parameter in the past and it worked.

I traced it back to using "from __future__ import annotations".  Only one parameter seems to be required in that case.

Comment: Hey Dennis! Welcome to Stack Overflow. You'll notice you can comment directly on answers for content like this. Stack Overflow doesn't use a forum type of model, so please only use answers for submitting solutions to the problem.

Comment: Oh yeah, I meant to do exactly that.  But typing reply then creating new account, it redirected me back but with the reply in the wrong spot.  Ah well, next time!  :)